# Pandas columns are showing in '.head()', but not in '.columns'

Tags: python, pandas

I imported the HousePrices dataset from Kaggle, displayed the rows at the beginning, but when calling `df.columns`, I only get the following output:

[image]

Calling `df.colums`:

```
houseprices.columns
```

output:

```
Index(['sep=', 'Unnamed: 1'], dtype='object')
```

I don't have any idea of what is happening hear, so I would be grateful for an explanation and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify in `pd.read_csv` if the dataframe contains column names. Because you did not do that, the columns are the first row of your dataframe. That's why when you use `.head()`, you get the 5 first rows, from which the first is the columns' names.

Try this:

```py
houseprices = pd.read_csv('.\\trains.csv', sep=',', header=0)
```

Read the full documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: Just fyi, it should be `header = 1` (else per docs, the default behaviour is `header = 0` and they'll get the same results)